# Parametric solutions of Pell's equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Given a positive integer $n$ which is not a perfect square, it is well-known that
[Pell's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) $a^2 - nb^2 = 1$ is always solvable in non-zero integers $a$ and $b$.

> **Question:** Let $n$ be a positive integer which is not a perfect square.
>   Is there always a polynomial $D \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ of degree $2$, an integer $k$ and
>   nonzero polynomials $P, Q \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $D(k) = n$ and $P^2 - DQ^2 = 1$,
>   where $a = P(k)$, $b = Q(k)$ is the fundamental solution of the equation
>   $a^2 - nb^2 = 1$?
>
> If yes, is there an upper bound on the degree of the polynomials $P$ and $Q$ --
>   and if so, is it even true that the degree of $P$ is always $\leq 6$?

**Example:** Consider $n := 13$.
Putting $D_1 := 4x^2+4x+5$ and $D_2 := 25x^2-14x+2$, we have $D_1(1) = D_2(1) = 13$.
Now the fundamental solutions of the equations
$P_1^2 - D_1Q_1^2 = 1$ and $P_2^2 - D_2Q_2^2 = 1$ are given by

- $P_1 := 32x^6+96x^5+168x^4+176x^3+120x^2+48x+9$,
- $Q_1 := 16x^5+40x^4+56x^3+44x^2+20x+4$

and

- $P_2 := 1250x^2-700x+99$,
- $Q_2 := 250x-70$,

respectively. Therefore $n = 13$ belongs to at least $2$ different series whose solutions
have ${\rm deg}(P) = 6$ and ${\rm deg}(P) = 2$, respectively.

Examples for all non-square $n \leq 150$ can be found [here](https://stefan-kohl.github.io/problems/pellpolynomials.txt).

**Added on Feb 3, 2015:** All what remains to be done in order to turn
Leonardo's answers into a complete answer to the question is to find out which values
the index of the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{n}]$ in the group of units
of the ring of integers of the quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})$
can take. This part is presumably not even really MO level, but it's just
not my field -- maybe someone knows the answer?

**Added on Feb 14, 2015:** As nobody has completed the answer so far, it seems
this may be less easy than I thought on a first glance.

**Added on Feb 17, 2015:** Leonardo Zapponi has given now a complete answer to
the question in [this note](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.00637v1).

Comment: This is curve defined over Q and of degree 2. So it will be a rational curve if it has a point defined over Q. For the so called Pell's equation the hypothesis holds.

Comment: @PVanchinathan: Sorry, but I don't understand your comment -- could you elaborate?

Comment: I think it is misleading to say that $n=13$ belongs to two series. Changing the parameter $k$ in your example changes all three variables in the Pell equation $a^2-nb^2=1$, including $n$.

Comment: @GHfromMO: The latter is true (of course!) -- but what does it have to do with the former? -- In what way do you think it is "misleading" to say that $n=13$ belongs to two series?

Comment: Well, saying that "$n=13$ belong to two series" suggests that you fix $n$ and look for parametric solutions of $a^2-nb^2=1$ in the remaining variables $a$ and $b$. Perhaps saying that the "initial value $n=13$ belongs to two series" would be more appropriate. This just a language thing, of course, because your question is clear about what you are after.

Comment: This is a guess, but I think the following is true: say $\sqrt{n}=[a_0;\overline{a_1,a_2,...,a_k}]$ - the periodic contiued fraction expansion. Then let $D(x)=[a_0x;\overline{a_1x,a_2x,...,a_kx}]^2$. I think $D(x)$ is integral, and from the convergents you get $P$ and $Q$. Maybe this $D$ doesn't work, but I definitely think something like this is the way to go.

Comment: Also, if the answer is yes, then the degress are definitely unbounded, since if $\sqrt{n}$ has a long period for its continued fraction, then $\sqrt{D}$ also has a long period, so $P,Q$ will be of large degree.

Comment: @DrorSpeiser: A main point is that you don't have $x$'es at every coefficient -- many (most) coefficients are constant throughout a series, and only some are variable and contribute to the degree.

Comment: @StefanKohl: Oh! Right. I missed that. Maybe it is bounded!

Comment: @StefanKohl: I was referring to rational parametrization   obtained by projection for any conic; the correspondence, barring a few finite exceptions,  between rational points on $P^1$ and the curve will in general be given by polynomials with rational coefficients, I am not sure now it is possible to guarantee integer coefficients.

Comment: I think i have done these equations with D=constant; In this special case then P and Q can be of any degree. But one can get an infinite number of solutions with the degree being always equal to 2.
I am sure this is not what you asked but.......the simplest answer can always be expressed with a polynomial of degree 2.{Note here that D has degree zero!!!]

Comment: Dear Stefan, I know have a complete proof that if $n$ is square-free then the degree of $P$ is bounded by $6$. I'm writing a short, summarizing note; you will receive it shortly.

Comment: The note is now available [here](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~leonardo.zapponi/leo_divers/Parametric_Pell.pdf). It is a draft version, which might soon be modified. It turns out that the possible degrees for $P$ are $1,2,3$ and $6$ (and they actually all occur).

Comment: @Leonardo: Thank you! But hmm: the degrees $4$ and $5$ do occur as well -- for example,
solutions are $D = 16x^2+16x+12$, $P = 32x^4+64x^3+64x^2+32x+7$, $Q = 8x^3+12x^2+8x+2$
and $D = 625x^2+125x$, $P = 1600000x^5+800000x^4+140000x^3+10000x^2+250x+1$,
$Q = 64000x^4+25600x^3+3360x^2+160x+2$. -- How do you explain these?

Comment: Dear Stefan, the possible degrees are $1,2,3$ and $6$ if $n$ is square-free. The examples you give in the above comment correspond respectively to $n=12$ (for $x=0$) and $n=500$ (for $x=-1$), which are not square-free.

Comment: @Leonardo: I see. -- And which degrees can occur for $n$ which are *not* square-free?

Comment: This is not yet clear... I will work on the question.

Comment: I actually believe that in the general situation the degree of $P$ is unbounded. Take for example $n=5043$ and the fundamental solution $a=5042$ and $b=71$. We then have the parametric solution $D=2825761X^2+275684X+5043$, $P=12464273528384X^7+4256093399936X^6+609867042064X^5+47472784800X^4+2165222136X^3+57799504X^2+835457X+5042$ and $Q=7414796864X^6+2170184448X^5+259142960X^4+16137600X^3+552024X^2+9824X+71$.

Comment: Actually, as shown in the remark at the end of the (updated) note, if we don't assume that $n$ is square-free then any degree can occur.

Comment: @Leonardo: Very interesting! – I have now added a reference to your note to your first answer, and accepted that answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let $n$ be a positive integer which is not a square and consider a fundamental solution $(a,b)$ of Pell's equation
$$a^2-nb^2=1.$$
Setting
$$\begin{cases}
D=(a+1)^2b^2X^2+2(a+1)^2X+n,\\
P=b^4(a+1)X^2+2b^2(a+1)X+a,\\
Q=b^3X+b,
\end{cases}$$
we have the identity
$$P^2-DQ^2=1,$$
with $D(0)=n,P(0)=a$ and $Q(0)=b$. This explicitly answers the (first) question. A second post (below) shows that if $n$ is square-free and congruent to $3$ modulo $4$ then the degree of the polynomial $P$ is at most $2$.

In the rest of the post, we briefly sketch how the polynomials $P,Q$ and $D$ were constructed: let $P,Q,D\in\Bbb C[X]$ be three polynomials with
$$P^2-DQ^2=1$$
and $\deg(D)=2$. Here, we assume $\deg(P)=d>1$, so that $\deg(Q)=d-1$. Consider the polynomial $f=P^2$, so that $f'$ has degree $2d-1$. Setting $$P=u\prod_{i=1}^r(X-x_i)^{e_i}\quad\mbox{and}\quad Q=v\prod_{i=1}^s(X-y_i)^{f_i},$$
with $u,v\in\Bbb C,r\leq d$ and $s\leq d-1$, we obtain the factorization
$$f'=\prod_{i=1}^r(X-x_i)^{2e_i-1}\prod_{i=1}^r(X-y_i)^{2f_i-1}R,$$
with $R\in\Bbb C[X]$. Since $d=\sum_{i=1}^re_i=1+\sum_{i=1}^sf_i$, we find the identity
$$2d-1=\sum_{i=1}^r(2e_i-1)+\sum_{i=1}^s(2f_i-1)+\deg(R)=4d-2-r-s+\deg(R),$$
which leads to
$$r+s=2d-1+\deg(R).$$
It then follows that $r=d,s=d-1$ and $\deg(R)=0$, i.e. $P$ and $Q$ are separable. Remark that the polynomial $D$ is then itself separable. In this case, the cover $\Bbb P^1\to\Bbb P^1$ induced by $f$ is only ramified above $\infty,0$ and $1$, i.e. it is a Belyi map. The isomorphism classes of such covers are classified by Grothendieck's dessins d'enfants and, once we have fixed the integer $d$, there is a unique class with the above ramification data (totally ramified above $\infty$, all the points above $0$ have ramification index $2$ and the points above $1$ have ramification $2$ excepted two of them, which are unramified, corresponding to the roots of $D$). More precisely, if $T_d\in\Bbb Z[X]$ denotes the Chebyshev polynomial (of the first kind) of degree $d$, there exist constants $\lambda\in\Bbb C^\times$ and $\nu\in\Bbb C$, such that
$$f=\frac{T_{2d}(\lambda X+\nu)+1}2=T_d(\lambda X+\nu)^2.$$
This shows how to construct $P$. For example, in individ's answer, we find
$$P=T_2(\lambda X+\nu),$$
with $\lambda=\frac{\sqrt{2}}2$ and $\nu=\sqrt{2}$, while $\lambda=169i$ and $\nu=-99i$ (with $i^2=-1$) leads to Will Jagy's example for $n=29$.

We can then try to find a solution for general $n$ from the case $d=2$ in the above discussion. Consider a fundamental solution $(a,b)$ of the Pell's equation $a^2-nb^2=1$. It is clear that in Stefan Kohl's question, we can reduce to the case $k=0$.We have the identity $T_2=2X^2-1$ and we therefore set
$$P=2(\lambda X+\nu)^2-1.$$
The condition $P(0)=a$ leads to the relation $\nu=\frac12\sqrt{2a+2}$, while $P\in\Bbb Z[X]$ gives the identity $P=NX^2+MX+a$, with $N$ and $M$ integers such that $4(a+1)N=M^2$. We then find the factorization
$$P^2-1=\left(\frac14M^2X^2+M(a+1)X+nb^2\right)\left(\frac M{2(a+1)}X+1\right)^2.$$
Finally, setting $M=2(a+1)b^2$, we can factor $b^2$ on the first factor of the above identity and put it in the second factor, which leads to the result.

**Added on Feb 17, 2015:** A complete answer to the question can be found in [this note](http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.00637).

Comment: Great! -- Thank you! -- Can you also say something on whether there exist series where $P$ has degree larger than $6$, or whether the degree of $P$ is bounded at all?

Comment: A table of Leonardo's polynomials for $n \leq 100$ is available [here](http://www.gap-system.org/DevelopersPages/StefanKohl/problems/leonardopols.txt).

Comment: Dear Stefan, I found a partial answer concerning the degree of $P$. In order to keep the above comments consistent, instead of editing my answer, I decided to write a new post.

Comment: It can be proved that setting $P_1=P(c^{-1}X), Q_1=Q(c^{-1}X)$ and $D_1=D(c^{-1}X)$, with $c=\mbox{gcd}\left(b^3,(a+1)b,2(a+1)^2\right)$ we obtain the parametric solutions whose coefficients have the smallest absolute values (try for $n=31,a=1530$ and $b=273$). Indeed, given $n,a$ and $b$, all the parametric solutions (for $P$ of degree $2$) are given by $P_1(mX),Q_1(mX)$ and $D_1(mX)$, with $m\neq0$ integer.

Comment: Very nice -- thank you! -- A table of these polynomials for $n \leq 100$ can be found [here](http://www.gap-system.org/DevelopersPages/StefanKohl/problems/leonardopolsminimal.txt). -- Though compare e.g. the polynomial $D = 821559147201x^2+14158405x+61$ you obtain for $n = 61$ with the one for the degree-6-solution ($100x^2-44x+5$) [here](http://www.gap-system.org/DevelopersPages/StefanKohl/problems/pellpolynomials.txt) ... .

Answer (score 4):

Not sure degree 6 is necessary. See what you can do with
$$  n=29, \; k=1, \; D = 169 x^2 - 198 x + 58, $$
$$  n=53, \; k=1, \; D = 625 x^2 - 886 x + 314, $$

The coefficient of $x^2$ seems to be $w^2,$ where $v^2 - n w^2 = -1.$ Such a $w$ is guaranteed to exist when $n \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ is prime.

Ummm; the discriminants of the quadratic forms $169 x^2 - 198 xy + 58y^2$ and $625 x^2 - 886 xy + 314y^2$ are $-4.$ Same for $25 x^2 \pm 14 xy + 2 y^2$ and $x^2 + y^2,$ also the ones for primes $73,89,113,$ also cases where you found $P$ quadratic and $Q$ linear.

LATER: $29$ worked very well. 
$$  n=29, \; k=1, \; D = 169 x^2 - 198 x + 58, $$
$$ P = 57122 x^2 - 66924 x + 19603,  $$
$$ Q = 4394 x - 2574,  $$
$$ P^2 - D Q^2 = 1,  $$
$$ P(1) = 9801, \; Q(1) = 1820, \; D(1) = 29.  $$

Comment: Nobody said degree $6$ would be 'necessary' -- there are just series
where degree $6$ occurs. For example, as you correctly noticed,
$n = 29$ and $n = 53$ not only belong to the series with $D = 4x^2+4x+5$,
where the solution with $P$ of degree $6$ stems from
$\sqrt{D} = [2x+1,\overline{x,1,1,x,4x+2}]$ (odd period length, three
$x$-es occur -- thus $P$ has degree $2 \cdot 3 = 6$), but also
to the series with the two $D$ you mention and
$\sqrt{D} = [13x-8,\overline{2,1,1,2,26x-16}]$ and
$\sqrt{D} = [25x-18,\overline{3,1,1,3,50x-36}]$, respectively.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some results concerning the degree of the polynomial $P$. We only treat the cases where $n$ is a positive, square-free integer congruent to $3$ modulo $4$, showing that the degree of $P$ is less than or equal to $2$.

We start by the weaker assumption that, given the positive integer $n$ and a solution $(a,b)$ of Pell's equation $a^2-nb^2=1$, there exist polynomials $D,P,Q\in\Bbb Q[X]$ and a rational number $k$ such that $P^2-DQ^2=1$, with $D(k)=n,P(k)=a$ and $Q(k)=b$. Let $d$ be the degree of $P$. As mentioned in my other post, and following the conventions and results in David Speyer's answer, there exist constants $\alpha\in\Bbb C$ and $\beta,\gamma\in\Bbb Q$, with $\alpha^2,\gamma^2\in\Bbb Q$ such that
$$\begin{cases}
P=\pm T_d\left(\alpha(X+\beta)\right),\\
Q=\gamma U_{d-1}\left(\alpha(X+\beta)\right),\\
D=\gamma^{-2}\left(\alpha^2(X+\beta)^2-1\right),
\end{cases}$$
where $T_d$ (resp. $U_d$) denotes the degree $d$ Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind (resp. of the second kind). From the hypothesis on $P$, we can assume $\beta=0$. We have the identity
$$T_d+U_{d-1}\sqrt{X^2-1}=\left(X+\sqrt{X^2-1}\right)^d,$$
which leads to
$$P+Q\sqrt{D}=\left(\alpha X+\sqrt{\alpha^2X^2-1}\right)^d.$$
If $d$ is odd then the explicit expression of $T_d$ shows that $\alpha$ (and therefore $\gamma$) is rational. Evaluating at $k$, we then obtain the identity
$$a+b\sqrt{n}=\left(u+v\sqrt{n}\right)^d,$$
with $u,v\in\Bbb Q$. It then follows that $u+v\sqrt{n}$ is a unit in the ring of integers of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{n})$ and, since we are assuming $n\equiv3\pmod4$, the elements $u$ and $v$ are integers. In particular, for $d>1$, the couple $(a,b)$ cannot be a fundamental solution of Pell's equation.

From now on, we assume $d=2m$ even. For $\alpha\in\Bbb Q$, we proceed as above and deduce that $(a,b)$ cannot be a fundamental solution for $d>1$. Suppose then that $\alpha=\sqrt{w}$, we $w\in\Bbb Q$ not a square, so that $\gamma=t\alpha$, with $t\in\Bbb Q$. We have the relation
$$T_d+U_{d-1}\sqrt{X^2-1}=\left(X^2-1+2X\sqrt{X^2-1}\right)^m$$
and thus
$$P+Q\sqrt{D}=\left(\alpha^2X^2-1+2\alpha\sqrt{\alpha^2X^2-1}\right)^m.$$
Evaluating at $k$, we then easily obtain the identity
$$a+b\sqrt{n}=\left(u+v\sqrt{n}\right)^m,$$
with $u,v\in\Bbb Q$. Once again, for $m>1$, it then follows that the couple $(a,b)$ cannot be a fundamental solution, leading to the result.

A final remark: for general $n$, if $(a,b)$ is a fundamental solution then
$$a+b\sqrt{n}=\left(u+v\sqrt{n}\right)^r,$$
where $u+v\sqrt{n}$ is a fundamental unit of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{n})$. For example, in Stefan Kohl's example for $n=13$, we have
$$649+180\sqrt{13}=\left(\frac{11}2+\frac32\sqrt{13}\right)^3.$$
I'm definitely not an expert on this subject, but the above discussion combined with an explicit bound for the integer $r$ would lead to a bound for the degree of $P$ and therefore give a complete answer to the second question.

Comment: Interesting. -- Thank you! If one could show that, say, $r \leq 3$, would this imply that the degree of $P$ is at most $6$?

Comment: Exactly. Actually, the integer $r$ is equal to the order of the finite (cyclic) group $R^\times/\Bbb Z[\sqrt{n}]^\times$, where $R$ denotes the ring of integers of the quadratic field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{n})$. In any case, for a given $n$, the degree of $P$ is bounded; it only remains to prove that this bound does not depend on $n$ (and, ideally, that it equals $3$).

Answer (score 3):

For $\deg P = 1$ or $2$, yes. For $\deg P=1$, take
$$P(x) = Mx+a,\ Q(x) = b,\ D(x) = \frac{M^2}{b^2} x^2 + \frac{2 Ma}{b^2} x + n.$$
For $M$ a sufficiently divisible integer, this will have integer coefficients.
For $\deg P=2$, take
$$P(x) = (a+1) (Mx+1)^2 - 1,\ Q(x) = (Mx+1) b,\ D(x) = \frac{M^2(a+1)^2}{b^2}x^2+ \frac{2 M (a+1)^2}{b^2}x + n.$$
For sufficiently divisible $M$, this will have integer coefficients.

---

For $\deg P>2$, there will rarely be any solutions.

At the risk of confusion, I'm going to rename some variables: Our given solution to Pell's equation is $a^2 - d b^2 =1$, and our goal is to find integer polynomials $A(x)$, $B(x)$ and $D(x)$ such that $A(x)^2 - D(x) B(x)^2 = 1$ and $(A(0), B(0), D(0)) = (a,b,d)$. The degree of $A$ is $n$. (As Leonardo observes, we can always translate $x$ to assume the polynomials are being evaluated at $0$.) Cleaning up some of Leonardo's formulas, we get that
$$(A(x), B(x), D(x)) = (T_{n}(\alpha (x+ \beta)), \ \gamma U_{n-1}(\alpha (x+\beta)), \ \gamma^{-2} (\alpha^2 (x + \beta)^2 - 1))$$
for some constants $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$, where $T_n$ and $U_{n-1}$ are [Chebyshev polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) of the first and second kinds. Note the formula $T_n(x)^2 - (x^2-1) U_{n-1}(x)^2=1$.

Taking the ratio of the $x^2$ and $x$ terms in $D(x)$, we see that $\beta$ is rational. The $x^n$ and $x^{n-2}$ terms in $A(x)$ are $2^{n-1} \alpha^n$ and $\alpha^{n-2} (n 2^{n-1} + 2^{n-1} \binom{n}{2} \beta \alpha^2 )$. Taking the ratio of these, we deduce that $n 2^{n-1} + 2^{n-1} \binom{n}{2} \beta \alpha^2$ is rational, so $\alpha^2$ is rational.

For any given $n$, the equation $T_n(\alpha \beta) = a$ determines $\alpha \beta$ up to finitely many values. But we have also seen that $(\alpha \beta)^2$ is rational. But, for generic $a$, the Galois group of $T_n(x) = a$ should be dihedral of order $2n$, by Hilbert's irreducibility theorem.

I suspect that you might be able to get solutions whenever $a$ happens to be of the form $T_n(\sqrt{m})$ for some $m$ and some Chebyshev polynomial $T_n$, but I haven't thought it through carefully.

Comment: As your "sufficiently divisible" $M$, you can just take $b^2$.
Then for ${\rm deg} P = 1$, we obtain the very short expressions
$D(x) = b^2x^2+2ax+n$, $P(x) = b^2x+a$, $Q = b$.
These expressions yield solutions with much smaller coefficients
than Leonardo's. -- Thank you very much for this!
I have tabulated the polynomials for $n \leq 100$
[here](http://www.gap-system.org/DevelopersPages/StefanKohl/problems/speyerpols.txt).
With our setting $M := b^2$, your solution for ${\rm deg} P = 2$
however gets identical to Leonardo's solution.

Comment: Though I am not sure you are right where you say that for ${\rm deg} P > 2$ there would be "rarely any solutions" -- to me it seems there are *plenty* of them -- for a list of examples, see [here](http://www.gap-system.org/DevelopersPages/StefanKohl/problems/higherdegreepols.txt).

Comment: Hmm ... More than I would have naively guessed. I took the list of primitive solutions to Pell's equation for the first $60$ nonsquares http://oeis.org/A033313 and solved $T_3(x)=a$. There were rational roots in $12$ cases. I still think the density has to drop to $0$, but I wouldn't have guessed it was so common in the first $60$.

Comment: I have checked the first 10000 nonsquares in that sequence, and found that for 1793 of them, $T_3(x)-a$ has a rational root. Thus the density seems roughly the same as for the first 60 which you checked. -- Do you still think the density drops to 0?

Comment: Furthermore, $T_4(x)-a$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ for 151 among the first 1000 values of $a$, and $T_5(x)-a$ is reducible for 10 among the first 1000 values of $a$, and $T_6(x)-a$ is reducible for 311 among the first 1000 values of $a$, and $T_7(x)-a$ is reducible for 6 among the first 1000 values of $a$, and $T_8(x)-a$ is reducible for 151 among the first 1000 values of $a$.

Comment: Also, you say that "for generic $a$, the Galois group of $T_n(x)=a$ should be dihedral of order $2n$" -- what I observe from GAP computations is that for $n \geq 5$ this doesn't seem to be true -- e.g. if $T_5(x)-a$ is irreducible, I find that its Galois group is the semidirect product of ${\rm C}_5$ and ${\rm C}_4$, and for $n = 7$ I find it's a semidirect product of ${\rm C}_7$ and ${\rm C}_6$, and for $n=8$ it is 'often' a group of order 32.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I wrote too short. So will write more.  Our goal is to find out - is there a maximum degree of these polynomials? Therefore, to simplify calculations it is possible to choose any ratio of the Pell equation.  For example, for the equation:

$$P^2-DQ^2=1$$

Knowing the previous solution of the Pell equation $(P1;Q1)$ can be found following the $(P2;Q2)$. Where $(P;Q)$ the first solution of this equation. For this you can use the formula.

$$P_2=PP_1+DQQ_1$$

$$Q_2=QP_1+PQ_1$$

We will use such polynomials.

$$P=x^2+4x+3$$

$$D=x^2+4x+2$$

$$Q=x+2$$

We substitute these values into the formula can be obtained for other factor the polynomial. He will be a multiple of the square. This way you can be of any degree.

$$P=8x^8+128x^7+864x^6+3200x^5+7080x^4+9536x^3+7600x^2+3264x+577$$

$$D=16(x^2+4x+2)(x+2)^2(x^2+4x+3)^2$$

$$Q=2x^4+16x^3+44x^2+48x+17$$